# Find lowest consecutive value

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, array, vectors

I have created a program where I first set the size of the array and
how many times I will look for consecutive values, then I fill in the
array and finally I insert the consecutive values, it should look for
the least consecutive value it finds in the array.

consecutive value means the sum of the elements in the array
consecutively.

example:

```
7 4 // Array size and consecutive values
6 4 2 7 10 5 1 // arrangement
1 3 4 2 // Consecutive values

Answer = 1,12,19,6
```

Explanation

> The lowest element of the array is the one in the last position which
> is 1, the answer is equal to 1.
>
> the lowest segment is the one furthest to the left 6 4 2, the sum of
> which equals 12.
>
> the answer is obtained by choosing segment 6 4 2 7, which equals 19.
>
> there are two segments with a minimum cost equal to 6, segments 4 2
> and 5 1.

How can it be improved?

```c++
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void suma_elementos(int elemento);
vector<int>elementos, consecutivos;
int n, q, consecutivo, total, final = 99999999;

int main()
{
    cin >> n >> q;
    elementos.resize(n);
    consecutivos.resize(q);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> elementos[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        cin >> consecutivos[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        suma_elementos(consecutivos[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < consecutivo; j++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < consecutivos[i]; c++)
            {
                total += elementos[c + j];
            }

            if (total < final)
            {
                final = total;
            }
            total = 0;
        }
        cout << final << " ";
        //reset
        consecutivo = 0;
        final = 99999999;
        total = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

//Suma de elementos
void suma_elementos(int elemento)
{

    int proporcion = n;

    while (proporcion >= elemento)
    {
        proporcion--;
        consecutivo++;
    }
}
```

edit 1:The program in small arrangements works well, but in large ones it's very slow

edit 2:must not have negative numbers in the sequence

Comment: Since you want to optimise it, can you provide a file with the input values which can give measurable and consistent timings in the profiler ? Also to save the manual typing, and the delay introduced because of that, please add the code that reads from a file. Right now, `cin >> valor; 
        recorrido.push_back(valor);` this block cannot be profiled correctly, since time taken by a human to enter a number is far more than the time a `push_back` takes.

Comment: If this is a programming challenge, can you please add the `programming-challenge` flag and add a link to the challenge. Nice question otherwise.

Comment: Please post a samlpe, or two, input that shows that the program is slow.

Comment: Also, is it possible to have negative numbers in the sequence?

Comment: @akki That is not quite correct, as the contents of a file can be piped in to stdin. Reading from stdin with cin is a better choice, as you can profile with many different input files without recompiling, whereas reading from a hardcoded file makes testing and profiling much more cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Avoid globals. `consecutivo` is particularly confusing. It is too easy to miss the fact that it is reset to 0 at each iteration. Always prefer returning a value:

  ```
  int suma_elementos(int elemento)
  {
      int proporcion = n;
      int consecutivo = 0;
      while (proporcion >= elemento)
      {
          proporcion--;
          consecutivo++;
      }
      return consecutivo;
  }
  ```

  and use it in your loop as

  ```
      int consecutivo = suma_elementos(consecutivos[i]);
  ```
- Now it is obvious that `suma_elementos` does not really need to loop. You have an invariant `proporcion + consecutivo == n`. At the end of the last iteration you also have `proporcion == elemento`, which means that `consecutivo = n - elemento`. In other words,

  ```
  int suma_elementos(int elemento)
  {
      return n - elemento;
  }
  ```
- Now I would rather not bother to have `suma_elementos` at all (besides, with my poor Spanish I have an impression that the name is rather misleading). The loop would become

  ```
      for (int j = 0; j < n - consecutivos[i]; j++)
  ```

  Honestly, it is much easier to understand.
- `final = 99999999;` is very fragile. Consider a ramp-up loop:

  ```
    final = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < consecutivos[i]; j++) {
        total += elementos[j];
    }
  ```
- Your code complexity is \$O(n*k)\$ (`k` being a width of the window). Notice that after the ramp-up you don't need to recompute the sums of `k` elements: as the window shifts, one element enters, another leaves:

  ```
    final = total;
    for (int leave = 0, enter = base[i]; enter < n; leave++, enter++) {
        total += elementos[enter] - elementos[leave];
        if (total < final) {
            final = total;
        }
    }
  ```

  obtaining \$O(n + k)\$ complexity.